# How to patch a module level access of os.environ?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am writing test cases for a module `module.py` that imports from another module `legacy.py`. The `legacy.py` reads `os.environ["some_var"]` at module level. When I am trying to run test cases for `module.py`, they are failing with `KeyError` for `some_var` in `os.environ`.

This is how code looks like:

`module.py`

```py
from legacy import db

def fun():
    pass
```

`legacy.py`

```py
import os

env = os.environ["some_var"]

class db:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

When running test cases for `module.py`, I am getting `KeyError: 'some_var'`.

I tried patching `os` (at module level also putting it before importing from `module.py` in test file) but the import statement is run before it could be patched. I tried looking for similar question on StackOverflow but didn't find the exact problem I am facing here.

How can I mock it? Or any other suggestion to be able to run the test cases. Assume that I cannot modify the `legacy.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict). There is an example in official doc.

Here is a fully functional example based in your question.

**module.py**

```
import os


def get_env_var_value():
    env_var = os.environ['PATH']
    return env_var

print(get_env_var_value())
```

**test_module.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest import main, TestCase

import module

class MyClassTestCase(TestCase):

    @patch.dict('os.environ', {'PATH': '/usr/sbin'})
    def test_get_env_var_value(self):
        self.assertEqual(module.get_env_var_value(), '/usr/sbin')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Doesn't matter if the environment var is loaded in outside or inside the class/method scope, because you will mock for all test scope.